# Aircraft zones - what is meant by zone 999?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

There are designated zones where Positions/FINs are allocated - so components have both Part Numbers, Serial Numbers, Positions (or FINs for Airbus) and Zone classifications.

Does zone `999` refer to being "un-zoned" or "unclassified"? Or something else perhaps? Is this only concerning Airbus this or is it universal across all manufacturers?

[image: Excerpt from Airbus - a330 of the Electrical Routing ATA 24-92-02-34B]

*Figure: Excerpt from Airbus -  a330 of the Electrical Routing ATA 24-92-02-34B*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ATA-100 specification](https://www.aviationhunt.com/aircraft-zoning/) states zones numbered in the 9xx range are "Reserved for uncommon differences between aircraft types not covered by standard series numbers."